# formatting string from settings bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a string in the setting bundle in an iPhone project.

```
test string that formats something like this => string%@inside%dastring
```

with a string and an integer, then I use this string

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:stringFromBundle, replace_string, an_int_number];
```

but the result string is not formatted.
do I have to convert the string that I get from bundle to some other encoding ?

Comment: When you log stringFromBundle what do you get?

Comment: I get the string the way I was entered with the %@ and %d inside the string from the bundle. I am not sure why the string is not formatted with the call stringWithFormat. After the call I still get the string with formatting directive inside them.

Comment: How do you put that string into the bundle, and what method do you use to get it out?  Also, is there some reason it needs to be in the bundle as opposed to in your code to start with?

Comment: The string is rather big so I put it in the bundle than in the code. I was just separating the data from code. I put the string as an entry in the main bundle then calling the "objectForInfoDictionaryKey" function of NSBundle class. I didn't create a new settings bundle because there is not many data related to the code to put in a separate bundle.

Comment: I put the string, string%@inside%dastring in the info.plist file of my app, and got it out using the method you mentioned, and it worked fine as the format string in stringWithFormat:.  So, I'm not sure what's going on with your app.  Is your string in the info.plist?  And, how did you put it in, from Xcode, or did you edit the XML file outside of Xcode?

Comment: That is strange. I have it in the info.plist and I copy pasted it and edited afterwards to put the formatters in it. It is actually a url and a lengthy one. I checked the xml and it is there... but it is html encoded.. '&' is encoded into &amp;

Comment: forgot to add... No, I didn't edit the .plist file outside the xcode.